# Separar array si contienen misma id

Tags: php, array, codeigniter, id

Estoy haciendo un reporte con fpdf en el cual debo imprimir tablas dependiendo de si los array contienen o no un id en especifico.

Tengo este array llamado $listado_agrupaciones

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 44f98747-d05f-41d4-a27b-bd9c76ed3906
            [id_agrupacion] => 079e568d-4c1c-11ea-815b-0050561bc441

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5ddbc032-a9e4-402a-abc5-f45f2167443f
            [id_agrupacion] => 079e7bfe-4c1c-11ea-815b-0050561bc441
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7a6cf440-f3b0-4ae5-823b-ff83a01af6e1
            [id_agrupacion] => 079e568d-4c1c-11ea-815b-0050561bc441
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => c5c86a40-d143-4e11-bde6-145ff243581e
            [id_agrupacion] => 079e7bfe-4c1c-11ea-815b-0050561bc441

        )

)
```

Cada elemento del array contiene un id_agrupacion y necesito agruparlos si comparten el mismo id_agrupacion, este es mi intento:

```
 $listado_agrupaciones_final = [];

    foreach($listado_agrupaciones as $listado_agrupacion){
        if(!in_array($listado_agrupacion->id_agrupacion,$listado_agrupaciones_final ,true)){
            $listado_agrupaciones_final[] = $listado_agrupacion;
        }
    };

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($listado_agrupaciones_final ); echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear directamente un array en el cual las claves sean el `id_agrupacion` (`$listado_agrupaciones_final`), o bien mediante un array auxiliar crear un array que agrupe por id_agrupación con las mismas claves internas que tenías antes (`$listado_agrupaciones_final2`). Si sólo se trata de agrupar el primero es más sencillo, si vas a necesitar ordenar el segundo caso puede resultar de interés.

```
$listado_agrupaciones = array();
$elem1 =  array("id"=>"44f98747-d05f-41d4-a27b-bd9c76ed3906","id_agrupacion"=>"079e568d-4c1c-11ea-815b-0050561bc441");
$elem2 =  array("id"=>"45ddbc032-a9e4-402a-abc5-f45f2167443f","id_agrupacion"=>"079e7bfe-4c1c-11ea-815b-0050561bc441");
$elem3 =  array("id"=>"7a6cf440-f3b0-4ae5-823b-ff83a01af6e1","id_agrupacion"=>"079e568d-4c1c-11ea-815b-0050561bc441");
array_push($listado_agrupaciones,$elem1,$elem2,$elem3);


$listado_agrupaciones_final = [];
$listado_agrupaciones_final2 = [];
$auxiliar_id_agrupaciones = array();
$n = 0;

foreach($listado_agrupaciones as $listado_agrupacion){  
    //array con id_agrupación como key
$listado_agrupaciones_final[$listado_agrupacion["id_agrupacion"]][] = $listado_agrupacion["id"];
    //array de con id_agrupación como valor
    if (in_array($listado_agrupacion["id_agrupacion"],$auxiliar_id_agrupaciones)) {
        $key = array_search($listado_agrupacion["id_agrupacion"], $auxiliar_id_agrupaciones); 
        $listado_agrupaciones_final2[$key]["id"][] = $listado_agrupacion["id"];
    } else {     
        $listado_agrupaciones_final2[$n]["id_agrupacion"] = $listado_agrupacion["id_agrupacion"]; $listado_agrupaciones_final2[$n]["id"][] = $listado_agrupacion["id"];
        $auxiliar_id_agrupaciones[$n] = $listado_agrupacion["id_agrupacion"];
            $n++;
    }
}

echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($listado_agrupaciones_final ); 
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($listado_agrupaciones_final2 ); 
echo "</pre>";
```

Resultado

```
Array
(
    [079e568d-4c1c-11ea-815b-0050561bc441] => Array
        (
            [0] => 44f98747-d05f-41d4-a27b-bd9c76ed3906
            [1] => 7a6cf440-f3b0-4ae5-823b-ff83a01af6e1
        )

    [079e7bfe-4c1c-11ea-815b-0050561bc441] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45ddbc032-a9e4-402a-abc5-f45f2167443f
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_agrupacion] => 079e568d-4c1c-11ea-815b-0050561bc441
            [id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 44f98747-d05f-41d4-a27b-bd9c76ed3906
                    [1] => 7a6cf440-f3b0-4ae5-823b-ff83a01af6e1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_agrupacion] => 079e7bfe-4c1c-11ea-815b-0050561bc441
            [id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 45ddbc032-a9e4-402a-abc5-f45f2167443f
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

conociendo tu Array, yo haria lo siguiente. Crearia otro array con una primera key los valores de agrupacion, y como valor un array con los ids que hay que agrupar.

```
foreach($listado_agrupaciones as $listado_agrupacion){
   $agrupador = $listado_agrupacion->id_agrupacion;
   $listado_agrupaciones_final[$agrupador][] = $listado_agrupacion->id;
}
```

con esto, te va a generar un array $listado_agrupaciones_final de la siguiente manera:

```
array (
   "079e568d-4c1c-11ea-815b-0050561bc441" => array(
        "44f98747-d05f-41d4-a27b-bd9c76ed3906",
        "5ddbc032-a9e4-402a-abc5-f45f2167443f",
        ...
    )
   "otro_id_de_agrupacion" => array(
         "id_  ",
         "id_  ",
   ...
)
```

En este array, las keys son los id_agrupacion, y contienen arrays con los elementos id que coinciden.